# PySpark - How to turn duplicate rows into new columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Let's say we have a table of `clients` of the kind:

```
| id | Name |
|-----------|
| 1  | John |
| 2  | Bob  |
| 3  | Ella |
| 4  | Jim  |
```

and a table of `vehicles` for each client:

```
| id |client_id| vehicle |
|------------------------|
| 1  |    1    |  car1   |
| 2  |    2    |  car2   |
| 3  |    2    |  car3   |
| 4  |    2    |  car4   |
```

Now we can see that Bob has 3 cars. I would like to add these vehicles to the `clients` table in the way that it gains new column for each vehicle with the respective `client_id`.

It should look something like this:

```
| id | Name | vehicle1 | vehicle2 | vehicle3 |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 1  | John |   car1   |   null   |   null   |
| 2  | Bob  |   car2   |   car3   |   car4   |
| 3  | Ella |   null   |   null   |   null   |
| 4  | Jim  |   null   |   null   |   null   |
```

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach :

Just note that it *can be little slow* Since we are evaluating same dataset twice (first to find max length and second to derive final dataset using max lenght)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = df1.join(df2, [df1.id == df2.client_id], 'left_outer').groupBy(df1['id'],'Name').agg(f.collect_list('vehicle').alias('vehicle'))
df.show()
+---+----+------------------+
| id|Name|           vehicle|
+---+----+------------------+
|  1|John|            [car1]|
|  3|Ella|                []|
|  2|Bob |[car3, car4, car2]|
|  4|Jim |                []|
+---+----+------------------+
```

Find max length from all vehicles and derive final dataset

```
max_len = df.select(f.max(f.size('vehicle')).alias('max')).first()['max']


df.select('id', 'Name', *[df.vehicle[x] for x in range(max_len)]).show()
+---+----+----------+----------+----------+
| id|Name|vehicle[0]|vehicle[1]|vehicle[2]|
+---+----+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|John|      car1|      null|      null|
|  3|Ella|      null|      null|      null|
|  2|Bob |      car2|      car3|      car4|
|  4|Jim |      null|      null|      null|
+---+----+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not only did your solution came out on top by quite a margin in a little benchmark I have done for the two but also is really honestly quite elegant considering the ugly task required and employs some cool PySpark magic I wasn't aware of. I wish all the Stack Overflow answers were like this.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING:** This solution requires the data to which the `udf_numbering` is applied to be either on a single executor or at least that each id is completely contained within one executor. When run on multiple executors where data is dispersed randomly among them, each would get its own copy of the `id_dict` without considering the changes on the other executors.

Figured it out. Terribly slow but does the job.

UDF:

```
id_dict = {}

def numbering(id):
    id = str(id)
    if id in id_dict:
        value: int = id_dict.get(id)
        br_dict[id] = value + 1
        return str(value)
    else:
        br_dict[br_id] = 1
        return str(1)

udf_numbering = udf(lambda id: numbering(id))
```

And then for `vehicles_df`:

```
vehicles_df = vehicles_df.withColumn('number_repeated', udf_numbering(col('client_id')))
vehicles_df = vehicles_df.groupBy('client_id').pivot('number_repeated').agg(first('vehicle'))
```

and we join into `clients_df`:

```
clients_df = clients_df.join(vehicles_df, vehicles_df('client_id') == clients_df('id'), 'left')
```